# How can I check the 13th number

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^(((\d{2}((0[13578]|1[02])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|(0[13456789]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|02(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))|([02468][048]|[13579][26])0229))(( |-)(\d{4})( |-)(\d{3})|(\d{7}))$/
```

I have the above regex. It checks all things correctly except on position 11 of my 13 digit number I am validating I want it to accept only 0 or 1. I am not sure where exactly in this expression should I put my [0-1].

For example:  Given 8001015009**0**87. This number would be valid but if I change 0 in position 11 to any digit which is not 0 or 1, then the number would not be valid

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide some example strings?

Comment: Regexen this long are actively user hostile and take an enormous amount of time and energy to just read and understand, **especially if you have absolutely no information on what they're supposed to do.** 1) I'd try to ditch this regex and write more understandable code that does the same thing, 2) at the very least give us here more information to work with, help us help you.

Comment: It looks like your expression is validating dates. Is there a reason you're using so many capture groups? There are several paths in your expression that will never be used, these could be removed for simplicity. Not all years ending in `00` are leapyears.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lookahead like this `(?=.{10}[01])(?=.{12}[01])` which will lookahead and validate the 11th and 13th character are either a `0` or a `1`.

`^(?=.{10}[01])(?=.{12}[01])(((\d{2}((0[13578]|1[02])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|(0[13456789]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|02(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))|([02468][048]|[13579][26])0229))(( |-)(\d{4})( |-)(\d{3})|(\d{7}))$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Ro Yo Mi thanks very much. You are some genius. It worked. I just wanted to check position 11 so I edited your answer and voila, it worked. Thanks once again. Below is what I now have and its working:                                                             /^(?=.{10}[01])(((\d{2}((0[13578]|1[02])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|(0[13456789]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|02(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))|([02468][048]|[13579][26])0229))(( |-)(\d{4})( |-)(\d{3})|(\d{7}))$/

Answer (score -1):

My mistake with 13. I though it's supposed to be a position, it is a number of digits. Correcting...

```
^(\d{10}[10])\d+
```

Comment: `^(\d{12}[10]|\d{10}[10])d+$` will allow the 13th or 11th character to be any number providing at least one of the positions are a `1` or a `0`.

Comment: Why are you mentioning *`position 13`*? OP is only interested about `[01]` on position 11.

Comment: Daaamn i did not read carefully. I red 11 and 13 position and there is 11position in 13digit number. My bad!